# Routing url becomes empty string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs v1.4.8. In this, I met with an issue regarding url binding. I use a file uploader programatically triggered by an image click event. While doing this, the url gets removed from the browser. This is the result I can see in my application.

Before click: http://localhost:49573/req/request.html#/req/upload

After click: http://localhost:49573/req/request.html#

**HTML code**

```
<img src="images/upload.png" title="Upload" ng-click="triggerupload()">
```

**The function inside controller**

```
       $scope.triggerupload = function () {            //ls_val
            alert($location.path());  
        };
```

> This returns /req/upload

**App.run**

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            console.log($location.path());
    });
```

> This returns empty string

Comment: are you using ngRouter or uiRouter (with `$state`) ? Because you add the tag ui-router but seems not to be using it.

Comment: As a side note when logging the location from the `$locationChangeStart` watch, you should rather use the `.oldUrl` and `.newUrl` fields of the `$locationChangeStart` event.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is most likely propagated to an outer scope that proceeds to change the location and thus emits the `$locationChangeStart`.

You should try to stop the propagation of the event from your `triggerupload` function :

```
$scope.triggerupload = function (event) {
    //do the upload
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Or directly in the `ng-click` directive :

```
<img ng-click="triggerupload(); $event.stopPropagation();" src="images/upload.png" title="Upload">
```

Comment: This stopPropagation() is not doing good for me. It still works as same. How do you say event propagates to an outer scope. I use only a simple alert in that.

Comment: When you click the image, a click event is generated. It will be first intercepted by your image's ng-click, but if you don't stop its propagation it will bubble to your image's container and up to the $rootscope